# Can I access OpenType features with CoreText that have no AAT equivalent?

Tags: ios, core-text, opentype

I want to create an iOS app that uses OpenType features of fonts that have no equivalent in AAT-fonts. Specifically I want to use the "ssty" feature of OpenType-Math fonts. This is a substitution feature that substitutes glyphs by slightly bolder variants that look better in sub/superscripts and fractions and are to be rendered at a smaller size. Ideally I don't want to use any third party libraries such as harfbuzz if it is possible doing this with CoreText only.

I tried the following code

```
CTFontRef font = ...; // this is the font I already set up without the ssty feature
// ...
NSArray *ssty_setting = @[ @"ssty", @1 ];
NSDictionary *font_attributes = @{ (__bridge NSString *)kCTFontFeatureSettingsAttribute : @[ssty_setting ] };
CTFontDescriptorRef font_feature_descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateWithAttributes((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)font_attributes);
CTFontRef font_with_features = CTFontCreateCopyWithAttributes(font, 0.0, NULL, font_feature_descriptor);
```

but when I use the new font_with_features to retrieve the glyph indices I want to render (using a `CTLineRef`) I still get back the not-substituted Glyph codes so it seem this approach doesn't work.

Also  another problem with the "ssty"-feature is that it only works in the OpenType-Script with tag "math" using the default OpenType language. However I don't see any possibility in CoreText to change the OpenType Script. I'd love to be proved wrong.

Aside of that think it should work because in the CTFontDescriptor.h Header (though not in the docs) Apple says:

```
Starting with OS X 10.10 and iOS 8.0, settings are also accepted (but not returned) 
in the following simplified forms:
An OpenType setting can be either an array pair of tag string and value 
number, or a tag string on its own. For example: @[ @"c2sc", @1 ] or 
simply @"c2sc". An unspecified value enables the feature and a value of 
zero disables it.
```

It seems like they don't accept arbitrary string tags...

I hope there is a way of doing this using CoreText and I'd really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: but which font were you using, and can you prove (with a dictionary tags header dump from the font for instance) that it really has the ssty feature you're trying to use?

Comment: I tried with various fonts (Latin Modern Math, Cambria Math and others). I am sure the ssty feature is available as I am successfully using it with an implementation I wrote using harfbuzz. The otfinfo cli-tool and fontforge also list the ssty feature for the fonts. 

This is most probably not a font issue but a missing feature in CoreText as far as I can tell. I don't think it is possible to access arbitrary features (which are not predefined by apple) from opentype fonts without parsing the font-tables oneself. 

I have thus pretty much given up trying to use CoreText and went with harfbuzz.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your suggestion but as I elaborate in the other comment I think this problem has no solution using sole CoreText.